# Vim visual mode 'w' select

Tags: vim, gvim

When using gvim 7.3, I can select a word by typing v and then w. The word selected does not include the punctuation after the word. When using vim 7.2 on Linux, selecting a word by typing v and then w also selects the following punctuation.

```
For example with this text and the cursor at the beginning of the line:
clk : in

On Windows, v w y o esc p produces
clk : in
clk 

On Linux, v w y o esc p produces
clk : in
clk :
```

Note the extra colon on Linux

Why is this? How can I make VIM on Linux behave like gvim on Windows (or vice-versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vw` will select the text from the cursor to the end of the current "word", where "word" is a sequence of characters from the set defined by the 'iskeyword' option. The 'iskeyword' option defaults to the set of ASCII alphanumeric characters plus underscore (_).

If `vw` is selecting more than that, then something, probably a filetype plugin, has added characters to 'iskeyword' to be, in the plugin author's opinion, more useful when editing the current file type. To find out where `iskeyword` is being set, execute

```
:verbose set iskeyword?
```

It may be that your Windows Vim installation has a different set of plugins than your Linux Vim installation, or that your Linux ~/.vimrc has filetype detection enabled and your Windows ~/_vimrc does not.

That behavior can be changed, but how it can or should be changed will depend on the behavior you want and how `iskeyword` is being set.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I checked iskeyword and it is the same on both systems. Looks like the default as you suggested.

Comment: Did you check 'iskeyword' immediately after you observed the difference in behavior of `w`? The value of 'iskeyword' can change while you're using Vim because of the behavior of plugins. Another thing to try would be to start vim and gvim with the options `-N -u NONE -i NONE` and see if you still observe the difference in behavior of `w`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `viw` to select an "inner word" (thats without the surrounding punctuation).
`viwoESCp` would then produce the same output as your windows version.